# Flutter navigator pop only when an AlertDialog is shown

Tags: flutter

I want code like `Navigator.of(context).pop();` to run only if there's a dialog shown like one called via `showGeneralDialog()`. If there's no dialog left, I want it to do nothing instead of making my scaffold dismissing and the screen goes black. Is there a way to do that?

My code to show the popup dialog (ignore this bloaty helper, let just think of simple dialog called in flutter):

```
Future showAlert({String title, Widget header, Widget dialog, Widget body, Widget listView, EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding, bool barrierDismissible = true, bool showButton = true, String buttonText = "OK", Widget customButton, Color warnaAksen}) {
  playSound("butt_press.wav");
  return showGeneralDialog(
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
    transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
      final curvedValue = Curves.easeInOutBack.transform(a1.value) - 1.0;
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).copyWith(id: 'general_dialog', data: ThemeData(
          dialogBackgroundColor: h.cardColor(),
          primarySwatch: warnaAksen ?? THEME_COLOR,
          fontFamily: THEME_FONT,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            bodyText1: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Lato", color: textColor()),
            bodyText2: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Lato", color: textColor()),
            button: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: THEME_COLOR)
          )
        )).data,
THEME_FONT,),
        child: Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(1.0, 1.0 + curvedValue, 1.0),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: a1.value,
            child: dialog ?? AlertDialog(
              shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
              title: header ?? (title != null ? Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0, color: textColor()),) : null),
              titlePadding: header != null ? EdgeInsets.zero : EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0, top: 24.0),
              content: listView ?? SingleChildScrollView(child: body,),
              contentPadding: contentPadding ?? EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, top: (title != null || header != null) ? 12.0 : 24.0, right: 24.0, bottom: 24.0),
              actions: showButton ? <Widget>[
                customButton ?? SizedBox(),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: Text(buttonText, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ),
              ] : null,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    barrierLabel: '',
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => Container()
  );
}
```

What I have try:

```
// TODO FIXME when there's no dialogue, there's no need to do anything
closeDialog() => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
```

Comment: Provide the code you're trying to run.

Comment: @Abbas I've updated my post with the code I've run

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you, but I had a case where it was a problem if users close the dialog with backpress. What I did was use `onWillPopScope`, and set the `onWillPop` function to return `false`. This didn't let the user close the dialog, thus my default `pop()` was only popping the topmost dialog and not causing any problems to my route.

```
    showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        child: AlertDialog(
          //dialog details
        ),
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
      );
    },
  )
```